# plymouth-quit-wait.service does not stop, boot does not finish

Tags: arch-linux, gnome, plymouth

I have configured Plymouth with Gnome on Arch Linux and can boot without problem (as in I enter my encryption key, get to the login screen, and can successfully log in). Unfortunately, `plymouth-quit-wait.service` never finishes:

```
~ systemctl status plymouth-quit-wait

● plymouth-quit-wait.service - Hold until boot process finishes up
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/plymouth-quit-wait.service; static)
     Active: activating (start) since Wed 2020-08-19 11:37:12 CEST; 4min 31s ago
   Main PID: 603 (plymouth)
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 38119)
     Memory: 312.0K
     CGroup: /system.slice/plymouth-quit-wait.service
             └─603 /usr/bin/plymouth --wait

Aug 19 11:37:12 hostname systemd[1]: Starting Hold until boot process finishes
```

I don't understand the reason for this, as everything works fine. Where could I look for troubleshooting?

Comment: If you run `systemctl status` with no further parameters, what do the first 4 or so lines say? If the start-up is truly finished, there should be `State: running` and `Jobs: 0 queued`. Also, `plymouth --wait` is waiting for the `plymouthd` process to exit - has that actually happened?

Comment: `State: starting. Jobs: 3 queued. Failed: 0 units`.
`systemctl list-jobs` lists `multi-user.target` and `graphical.target` as waiting and `plymouth-quit-wait.service` as running.
The `plymouthd` process is still running. Can I somehow look at its output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments, the problem seems to be that `plymouthd` is still running, and `plymouth-quit-wait.service` is waiting for it to exit.

Because `plymouthd` needs to start in initramfs and keep running at least until the GUI server (whether X11 or Wayland) starts, at least on Debian its service names are a bit unusual:

- `/lib/systemd/system/plymouth-start.service` actually starts `plymouthd` as a forking one-shot service, and tells it to start showing a boot splash screen.
- if necessary, `systemd-ask-password-plymouth.service` tells it to ask for things like disk encryption passphrases
- `plymouth.service` is a symbolic link to `plymouth-quit.service`, which is another oneshot service that runs `plymouth quit` that is supposed to tell `plymouthd` to exit.

Arch's setup may be somewhat different, but I gather that either some service is not running `plymouth quit` when it should, or `plymouthd` is not getting the message that it should exit.

You might try running `plymouth quit` manually as root - if that causes `plymouthd` to exit and `systemctl status` to transition to `State: running`, then the problem is about `plymouth quit` not getting executed automatically. If the state does not change, then try killing the `plymouthd` process, as it seems to be hung somehow.

Are you, by chance, using the proprietary NVIDIA GPU driver? If I recall correctly, there is/used to be an issue that it sets the display framebuffer configuration in such a way that `plymouthd` fails to work correctly with it. If so, then you might want to try a text-based plymouth boot theme, or disable the boot splash altogether.

Comment: Running `plymouth quit` as root works fine - it puts me back to the login screen. As you said, `systemctl status` prints `State: running` afterward. I only have an integrated Intel GPU, no NVIDIA GPU driver. Thanks for the help!